# SQL to combine 2 unrelated columns from 2 unrelated tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, relational-database, database-schema

I've been looking all over the Internet for a solution to this problem, but **nobody seems to have asked this question before**.

**2 unrelated tables, x columns each**. I want a very simple **result: to have the 2 columns one next to each other, but with the rows corisponding (row1-row1, row2-row2)**.

```
 I will elaborate in case it isn't clear to someone:
 ___________________

 -What I want to do, is to put 2 columns one next to each other:
    -table1.column1
    -table2.column1

  So the result would be something like this:
   table1.column1.ROW1 - table2.column1.ROW1
   table1.column1.ROW2 - table2.column1.ROW2
   table1.column1.ROW3 - table2.column1.ROW3
   table1.column1.ROW4 - table2.column1.ROW4
   table1.column1.ROW5 - table2.column1.ROW5
   ..etc..
 ___________________
```

A query like **"SELECT table1.column1, table2.column1 FROM table1, table2"** won't give me the wanted result, as it **outputs rows*rows**.

**IN CASE anyone is wondering why** in the world I would need to put 2 unrelated columns together from 2 unrelated tables:  **My job** is to go in a bank, take their  databases with clients' information, and mask all the data (in a certain way, not randomly). **In the end**, I have the original Table of the bank and its perfect clone - the clone Table being populated by the masked data.
**At that point**, the critical part kicks in:

- What I need to do is to compare column by column: 1 column from the
  original Table of the Bank with its clone - the same identical column, but with the masked data in it instead of the original data (which actually is a whole new column of a whole new Table).

In order to make sure that all the data has been masked properly, respecting all the criteria of the client (the bank), I need to put all the data from column X, right next to all the data from column Y, (row1-row1 ; row2-row2 ; etc).

What I currently do, is to take tens of printscreens and to compare them, which is wasting lots and lots and lots of time.

If anyone could come up with a solution to this problem I would eternally be grateful.

I should also mention that I have nothing to JOIN on, as all the data from table1 is completely different from all the data from table2, nothing in common.

---

**THE SOLUTION has been provided by the user 'sstan', and it works perfectly.**
**The query is:**

---

select table1.COLUMN, table2.COLUMN

from (select rownum as rn1, table1.COLUMN from YOURTABLE1.COLUMN table1) table1

join (select rownum as rn2, table2.COLUMN from YOURTABLE2.COLUMN table2) table2

on table1.rn1 = table2.rn2;

---

As you adapt this query to your tables, keep in mind that you have to replace just the words I've written in 'CAPITAL' letters.

The query works perfectly on larger datasets as well. I've tested it on 100.000 rows, every row is in his place, the 'rownum' function does not alter them at all.

**This is the best and fastest way to put 2 columns one right next to each other, with their rows matched, from 2 different tables (of 2 different users as well in my case), who have absolutely nothing in common to JOIN on.**

Comment: Will ROW_NUMBER() work for you?

Comment: Please post your table definitions as well as a sample of the data.

Comment: So if I have `table1.column1.row1`, how do I find the corresponding `table2.column1.row1`?  Is there a rule that allows you to match the 2?  Because if it's just row ordering, then you need to have something to order by.  Simply reading both tables top to bottom is not enough, as Oracle does not store rows in a specific or deterministic order internally.

Comment: The Table definitions have 3 pages each..

I 2 totally unrelated tables, from the same database, they have absolutely nothing in common.
I want to take column 1 and column 1 from table 1 and table 2.
The output result to be
row 1 - row 1
row 2 - row 2

Comment: All I know is that row1 from column1 must match row 1 from column 2. That's the only rule, and pretty much all I have to do.

Comment: Based on the information you have provided, I don't see how this is possible, unless you really don't care about matching up completely random rows together.  The concept of what is a `row1` or `row2` doesn't seem to be clearly identified.  It sounds like you could really have benefited from adding a surrogate key on `table1` ***before*** masking the data, so that you would have had something to match on.  I hope I'm misunderstanding you, and that there is a way to get what you want.

Comment: Basically I have to put these 2 queries in 1 query:
1: SELECT column1 from table1
2: SELECT column1 from table2

Comment: It is critical though that rows 1,2,3 from column1 match rows 1,2,3 from column2. This is the whole point

Comment: You would have to be extremely lucky for both tables to have their matching rows returned in the same order.  Never mind how to join them... when you query both tables separately, can you tell that the row order is not the same?  That's what I would expect.  And that's the problem.  If you can tell me with absolute certainty that when you do `select * from table1` and `select * from table2`, that both selects return things in the order you want, then there is hope, otherwise, you're in a pickle.

Comment: Yes 'sstan', the queries "select * from tables" return results in the exact order of the original data from the tables.

Comment: How can you tell if everything looks different?

Comment: I tried the query on a simpler table and the rows match

Comment: On a smaller table, I can see that happening.  Rows are probably returned in the order that Oracle inserted them.  And I posted the query you're looking for in my answer.  But I am telling you out of compassion, and just in case this is my bank you're dealing with :), this will most likely not work on a larger data set.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't. Alright then the alternative is not so bad after all, I was just hoping for a quicker way, but I guess I have to clone the original table, modify it and put a column in common with my masked table in order to Join on it. Thanks.

Comment: I am wondering why you aren't using the Oracle masking and column security options instead?

Comment: Because Micro Focus DataExpress is what my company chose.

Comment: My condolences :-)  Good luck

Comment: But does the Oracle masking work on Mainframe?

Answer (score 1):

Even though we mask the data, there should be some column with data that are common to both the tables.  Please have a look for the primary key columns and identity columns for common data - a suggestion.

we can display as per your requirement based on using `joins`.

Glad to help further

Here is the query.  Try something like this

```
create table table1(column1 varchar(255),column2 varchar(255));
insert into table1(column1,column2)values('a','a1');

--create temp table1
create GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp1(rownumber int,column1,column2);
insert into temp1 select Row_Number() Over(order by column1),column1,column2 from table1;

--create table2    
create table table2(column1 varchar(255),column2 varchar(255));
insert into table2(column1,column2)values('b','b1');

--create temp table2    
create GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp2(rownumber int,column1,column2);
insert into temp2 select Row_Number() Over(order by column1),column1,column2 from table1;

--join based on rownumber
select temp1.column1,temp2.column1 from temp1 join temp2 on temp1.rownumber=temp2.rownumber;
```

Hope this helps.  This should fix the issue.

Comment: This is why I have this problem, I have nothing to JOIN on. All the data from Table1 is completely different from all the data from Table 2. This is the point of masking. No data shall remain the same after masking, otherwise it could lead to who the actual client is.
Everything from Table 1 is different from everything from Table 2. 
Yet somehow, I must find a way to match rows from both tables, which I can do, but multiple times with "Select table1.column1, table2.column1 FROM table1, table2;" - that gives me the wanted result, but a lot others I don't need as well.

Comment: okay.  you explained me well.  Create two temporary tables for table1 and table2.  Add all the columns in the first table along with a column for ROW_NUMBER().Do the same for the second table.  Join both of them based on the ROW_NUMBER() column.  I am trying to post the code shortly.  Hope this should help.  Let's see

Comment: Hi @Robert, I have updated the answer with a sample code.  I will be very happy if that works for you.  **There is nothing impossible with Oracle**.  If this does not work, let me help you further or please mark it as answer.

Comment: I am not familiar to the concepts you used into the code, I will have to get home and give it a better look in detail. In the meantime I have edited my original post, look at the end of it, thanks.

Comment: It seems from the code you updated, there is a column named rownum in both the tables common.  Am I wrong?  If rownum is common I would ask you to try with this query 
`SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2
      FROM table1
      INNER JOIN table2
      ON table1.rownum = table2.rownum;`

Comment: rownum is not a column, rownum is a function. Try it yourself on a random table: "Select rownum FROM whateverTable". It's a fake column, or a virtual column, it doesn't actually exist, you can't call it with table1.rownum, you have to SELECT it in order to give a result.

Comment: For Your Information - In the code sample in the answer, I have used temp tables.  It will be very interesting to know about it as it is very helpful in real-world data operations.

Comment: @RobertStan - Okay. gotcha.  Let me try.  Temp tables are simple here.  Please try if that helps too.

Comment: I already have a complicated solution to the problem, I'm just in a search for a simple solution.
The complicated solution to the problem is to clone the tables, give them both 2 columns to have in common and join on, then I can manipulate them as I want. I will give your solution a look when I get home however. In the meantime, I'm trying find a much simpler solution, and that would be to get that query to work.

Comment: Adding a function to get the rownumber makes the query a little complex. Lets try that anyway.  If you got it right before my comment, just post it. Thanks @RobertStan

Comment: Problem solved mate. I have edited the original question, check the bottom of it for the perfect solution. Thank you for your help and time, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...)` OR `ROWNUM` to generate a pseudo-column to join the tables on. If you want the tables in a specific order for joining then you can specify this using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_name)`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e907/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE random1 ( ID1, VALUE1 ) AS
          SELECT 1, 20 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 32 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 5 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE random2 ( ID2, VALUE2 ) AS
          SELECT 6, 17 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 7 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID1,
       ID2,
       VALUE1 - VALUE2 AS difference
FROM   ( SELECT ID1,
                VALUE1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ) AS RN
         FROM   RANDOM1 ) a
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT ID2,
                VALUE2,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ) AS RN
         FROM   RANDOM2 ) b
       ON  ( a.RN = b.RN )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e907/11/0)**:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | DIFFERENCE |
|-----|-----|------------|
|   1 |   6 |          3 |
|   5 |   4 |         22 |
|   3 |   2 |         -2 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT ID1,
       ID2,
       VALUE1 - VALUE2 AS difference
FROM   ( SELECT ID1,
                VALUE1,
                ROWNUM AS RN
         FROM   RANDOM1 ) a
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT ID2,
                VALUE2,
                ROWNUM AS RN
         FROM   RANDOM2 ) b
       ON  ( a.RN = b.RN )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e907/11/1)**:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | DIFFERENCE |
|-----|-----|------------|
|   1 |   6 |          3 |
|   5 |   4 |         22 |
|   3 |   2 |         -2 |
```

Comment: I am not familiar to the concepts you used into the code, I will have to get home and give it a better look in detail. In the meantime I have edited my original post, look at the end of it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` both your tables on something like client ID number.

Comment: I have nothing to join on, the 2 tables are completely different. Sorry I haven't made that clear in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be something to 'JOIN' on. For example lets assume each row in both tables has a ClientID column

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column1 FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.ClientID = table1.ClientID
```

Comment: The client IDs are different, everything is different on table1 from table2.

In table 1 I have the veritable data, in table2 it's all the masked data, nothing matches.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not possible.

Simply doing `select * from table1` and `select * from table2` side-by-side will not magically pair up the rows the way you are expecting.  This is because you can't control how Oracle chooses the store the rows internally, or how it will return them to you (unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause).  That's not even taking into account that Oracle can move rows around as it sees fit when values are updated.

My recommendation: restart your masking process.  It's not too late, right?  You still have the original data.

But this time, before you do, add a new column on `table1` called `Id` or something.  It doesn't need to have some special value.  You can auto-generate it using a sequence.  Just make sure each row's Id is unique by creating a unique constraint on it, or better yet, define it as the primary key.

Then, when you mask all the data and place it in `table2`, make sure to store this `Id` value in the corresponding row of `table2`.

Only then will you be able to do what you are asking for with a query such as this:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1
join t2 on t2.Id = t1.Id
```

There is no way around this.

**EDIT:**

What you are asking for is this query:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select rownum as rn, t.* from table1 t) t1
join (select rownum as rn, t.* from table2 t) t2
  on t2.rn = t1.rn
```

But, I really don't see how your rows will just magically match the way you expect them too.  Hopefully you'll realize that.  And if so, I strongly urge you to consider my other option above.

**EDIT 2:**

I may not be a reliable source of information when it comes to Oracle.  But Tom Kyte is.  Please read the following thread and his answers.  I think this will help you understand the problem better:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6257473400346237629

Comment: The row1 ID from Table1 is different from row1 ID from Table2, so you predicted right that it won't work with that query.

Comment: The solution is indeed to clone the original table and put a column in common with the masked table in order to have something to join on. Thanks for your time

Comment: I am very happy to hear you say that :)

Comment: I was wrong. The solution you provided in the EDIT1 is the correct one. I've been testing it for hours on a 100.000 rows dataset. Absolutely all the rows match. Rownum is not altering the actual row number in any way. You solved my problem sir. Thank you!